# Populate data from one column to another column on condition in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

WE have :-
TABLE_1  having column (A_COL,NUM ) and TABLE_2 having column ( B_COL ,C_COL , NUM)

Q condition
   **If A_COL is NULL in the TABLE_1 then, populate the C_COL  into B_COL column from TABLE_2**

TRIED :-

Select 
    CASE WHEN A_COL IS NULL THEN B_COL = C_COL  end as ABC_COL
from line
FROM TABLE_2 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
TABLE_1 B
ON
A.NUM = B.NUM

I tried this but  B_COL = C_COL not able to populate column C_COL into B_COL ,Do we have any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below :

tab_1 as A and tab_2 as B

Selecting complete table 2 with condition :

```
 Select 
 B.colB,
 if ( A.colA = null , B.colB , B.colC) as B.colC,
 B.num
 from Tab_2 B
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 TABLE_1 A
 ON
 A.NUM = B.NUM
```

Let me know if it dint work out.